# Troubles with For Loop

Tags: vb.net

I loop through a series of 32 labels, wanting to apply a function to each and every one. But certain labels are different to each other, I have simplified the functions just to make it a bit easier to understand.

```
Dim allLabels() As Label = {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, ... Label32}
Dim fruits() As String = {"peach", "apple", "orange", "watermelon", "banana", "kiwi" ...}
Dim strBoolean = False

For Each aLabel As Label In allLabels
    For Each fruit As String In fruits
        Dim strFilepath = "C:\Ilikefruit\" + fruit

        If fruit = "apple" Then
            strFilepath = "C:\Ilikeapples\" + fruit

        ElseIf fruit = "orange" Then
            strFilepath = "C:\Ilikeoranges\" + fruit

        ElseIf fruit = "banana" Then
            strFilepath = "C:\Ilikebananas\" + fruit
            strBoolean = True
            Exit For
        End If

        aLabel.Text = strFilepath 
    Next

    If strBoolean = True Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

My problem is that it loops through the array of fruits again, in this case, it's adding the banana parameter to the apples directory, ultimately giving me an error. I have tried using `Exit For` but no luck. How can I break the link to only use the parameter once, then end the For Loop? Removing the parameters (apples, oranges, bananas) proves to work but obviously pastes the default directory.

Ultimately, I need every label to show `"C:\Ilikefruit\" + fruit` apart from the fruits I listed

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to process the items at the same index in each array as a pair, i.e. `Label1` and "peach", `Label2` and "apple", etc?  If so then don't use two nested `For Each` loops, which, by definition, pairs each item in one list with each item in the other list.  Use a single `For` loop and use the loop counter as an index into both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a wild guess here because this isn't very clear. First, separate your code into it's individual logic.

```
Function GetPathFromFruit(ByVal fruit As String) As String

    If fruit = "apple" Then
        Return "C:\Ilikeapples\" & fruit

    ElseIf fruit = "orange" Then
        Return "C:\Ilikeoranges\" & fruit

    ElseIf fruit = "banana" Then
        Return "C:\Ilikebananas\" & fruit
    End If

    Return "C:\Ilikefruit\" & fruit
End Function
```

Then loop by index, that way you'll be able to loop both array at the same time.

```
    For index As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(allLabels.Count, fruits.Count) - 1
        allLabels(index).Text = GetPathFromFruit(fruits(index))
    Next
```

Even better would be to have a class Fruit that takes care of returning the information.

```
Class Fruit

    Public Property FruitName As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal fruitName As String)
        _FruitName = fruitName
    End Sub

    Public Function GetFilePath()

        If _FruitName = "apple" Then
            Return "C:\Ilikeapples\" & _FruitName

        ElseIf _FruitName = "orange" Then
            Return "C:\Ilikeoranges\" & _FruitName

        ElseIf _FruitName = "banana" Then
            Return "C:\Ilikebananas\" & _FruitName
        End If

        Return "C:\Ilikefruit\" & _FruitName
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to ponder on, which I believe you may find very helpful:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim s1 As String() = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    Dim s2 As Integer() = {1, 2, 3}

    Console.WriteLine("Nested For Each Loops")
    For Each s1Item As String In s1
        For Each s2Item As Integer In s2
            Dim m As String = $"{s1Item}, {s2Item}"
            Console.WriteLine(m)
        Next
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Single For Loop, leveraging array indices")
    Dim itemsLengthMinimum As Integer = {s1.Length, s2.Length}.Min()
    For itemsIndex As Integer = 0 To itemsLengthMinimum - 1
        Dim s1Item As String = s1(itemsIndex)
        Dim s2Item As Integer = s2(itemsIndex)
        Dim m As String = $"{s1Item}, {s2Item}"
        Console.WriteLine(m)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Single For Each Loop, using Zip to return Object array")
    For Each pairedItem As Object() In s1.Zip(s2, Function(s1Item, s2Item) {s1Item, s2Item})
        Dim m As String = $"{pairedItem(0)}, {pairedItem(1)}"
        Console.WriteLine(m)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Single For Each Loop, using Zip to return Tuple")
    For Each pairedItem As Tuple(Of String, Integer) In s1.Zip(s2, Function(s1Item, s2Item) New Tuple(Of String, Integer)(s1Item, s2Item))
        Dim m As String = $"{pairedItem.Item1}, {pairedItem.Item2}"
        Console.WriteLine(m)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end...")
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

(Note, above example was done using VB version 15, Visual Studio 2017.)